# set clr support to true with cmake

Tags: cmake, clr, managed-c++

I am trying generate a managed c++ code with cmake. Below is the script which i have added for

```
 SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/clr") 
 STRING(REPLACE "/EHsc" "/EHa" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
 STRING(REPLACE "/RTC1" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
 SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /clr")
```

It does not set clrsupport to true.How do we do it cmake.

-swetha

Comment: What gets added to the compiler call? It could be, that you don't need to add the `/` in front of your flag.

Comment: I don't know if it's helpful at this point of time, but VS managed code project support is currently added to CMake to be release with the next revision (CMake > 3.7.0, see [here](https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=commitdiff;h=2e2ba95c))

Answer (score 10):

This does the trick for me, on Visual Studio 2017:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME "")
```

Note that the values "pure" and "safe" have been removed with Visual Studio 2017, and the empty string `""` as above will get you a "mixed" (native/managed) dll.

Answer (score 6):

I set the following property in my cmakelist it is now working

```
target_compile_options(${project_name} PRIVATE /clr)
target_compile_options(${project_name} PRIVATE /fp:precise) # /fp:strict is          
incompatible with /clr

set_property(TARGET ${project_name} PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_ROOTNAMESPACE ${project_name})

set_property(TARGET ${project_name} PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_KEYWORD "ManagedCProj")

set_property(TARGET ${project_name} PROPERTY VS_GLOBAL_CLRSupport "true")

set_property(TARGET ${project_name} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.0")

set_property(TARGET ${project_name} PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System" "System.Data" "System.Drawing" "System.Windows.Forms" "System.Xml")

# Note: Modification of compiler flags is required for CLR compatibility now that we are using .resx files.
string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
string(REPLACE "/RTC1" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
```

Comment: Maybe you should name/link the source of your answer. If I understand that correctly, what you have posted was proposed by Benjamin Ballet on the CMake mailing list as [an answer to your question](http://www.mail-archive.com/cmake@cmake.org/msg55716.html).

Comment: FWIW, my C/C++ Debug flags had both `/RTC1` and `-RTC1` populated. To remove them, I used the following: 
`string(REGEX REPLACE "[/|-]RTC[^ ]*" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})`

Comment: According to the CMake source code, the only thing setting `PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME` does is set the /clr compile-option. Seems oddly incomplete. So you should be able to replace `target_compile_options(${project_name} PRIVATE /clr)` with `set_target_properties(${project_name} PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME ""` and get rid of the warning.